jboss.management.http.port after change create "Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm"
I want to make jboss.management.http.port configurable.
When I run my batch file I want to change http management port so I added to batch file : -Djboss.management.http.port="19990"
but when the application is runing I have this: Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm.
How can I fix this problem ?
